# Zend Framework Routing Get Parameters

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller

With Zend Framework 1.10 I'm having a list with articles and an search field.
When typing something in the searchfield and hit the <kbd>search</kbd> button it generates me the following url:

```
https://example.org/products?category=12&no=
```

On the result of the searchpage you'll find the products matching to the search field.

If there are more than 10 products with the search attribute, there is a <kbd>next</kbd> button. For this <kbd>next</kbd> button im using the following code to generate the url, which will sadly not extend the already passed arguments (category and no).

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->next)); ?>">
<?php echo $this->translate('NextPage'); ?> &gt;
```

It will redirect me on https://example.org/products

How to add the already passed GET argument from the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the GET parameters from the search in the session so when you are requesting with the next url, you can retrieve the parameters previously entered in the search form.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you have an example?